# Using a GoLang Routine to Return to Multiple Threads

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine, channel

I am building an API that can queue up requests to GET an external website and subsequently perform some work by interacting with that API.  I am trying to figure out how to avoid duplicate
simultaneous go routines.

That is, assume a request comes in for http://www.example.com  The routine is launched to handle that URL which could last minutes or even hours.  Any number of other requests can come in while this is happening.  If the new requests are not already being worked on, they should proceed with their own routine to fulfill.

However, if another request for example.com comes in, I want the thread that request comes in on to block until the previous example.com request is complete and then it may proceed (duplication is fine, if the first task succeeded it will be a quick GET to confirm, if it failed, trying again is fine).

All of the code examples I've found use channels or waitgroups but these concepts all appear to only block one thread.  That is, the first example.com thread is waiting on say a channel to return a value, but I can't have example.com request #2 wait on that same channel since the result can only be read from the channel once.

If it makes any difference, I am building a worker pool with 5 workers, and a worker won't be allocated if another worker is already working the example.com request.

I've also considered using a buffer to keep track of the URLs that are currently being worked by the workers, but I wasn't sure how to block on waiting for the URL to be deleted from the buffer.  I saw an example using an infinite for loop and a break for when the URL is no longer in the buffer, but that seems like unnecessary CPU abuse (indefinitely doing a for range on the buffer looking for the URL to no longer be present and to then break).

How do I queue these requests up?

Edit: Solution I was looking for is signal channels.  Thanks to Burak Serdar for pointing me to it.  If anyone else needs this, Google "signal channels" and you'll find plenty of info.

Comment: Hi! If you don't want the result to be recalculated for every request (that's how I understand "the result can only be read from the channel once"), I'ld say utilize a cache. I don't really understand how that is related to the question of parallelization, though. A blocking channel might work well here: the request handler puts the request in a shared, blocking job queue /`channel` together with a newly created callback `channel` for the result, so it can wait for it. A worker puts the result into that callback `channel` there, which either stems from the cache or from recalculation.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by callback channel?  I googled it but didn’t see this concept phrased this way. By blocking channel I assume you just mean a channel that closes when the initial worker finishes (as Burak suggested).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: With "blocking" I meant: a job `channel` with buffer size of `0`. Any request who wants to add a new job to this channel will have to wait until it has been freed up. This way, the handling will take place sequentially. Regarding the callback `channel`: The request handler creates a `callback` channel and passes it to the worker by adding this info it to job in the the job `channel`. This way it will get passed to the worker who can then write the result into that callback `channel`. The handler is waiting for the result being added to that callback `channel` (via `select`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block a goroutine based on the URL, you can implement a scheme that looks like this:

First, keep a map of all URLs being worked on:

```
var urls = make(map[string]chan struct{})
var urllock = sync.Mutex{}
```

The following addURL will add a URL being worked on to the `urls` map if it is not there, and will return a channel to notify completion of that task. If the URL is already in the map, it will return false with a wait channel.

```
func addURL(u string) (bool,chan struct{}) {
   urllock.Lock()
   defer urllock.Unlock()
   ret, exists:=urls[u]
   if exists {
     return true,ret
   }
   ret=make(chan struct{})
   urls[u]=ret
   return false,ret
}
```

When you get a new URL to work on, try to put it on the map. If you can, then work on it:

```
workOnURL, ch:=addURL(newURL)
if workOnURL {
    go func() {
        defer removeURL(newURL)
        // Work on URL
    }()
} else {
  <-ch // Wait for the goroutine to finish
  // Then, you can try rescheduling the same URL, or do something else
}
```

With `removeURL`, remove the URL from the map, and close the channel, so any goroutine waiting for this to finish can continue:

```
func removeURL(u string) {
   urllock.Lock()
   defer urllock.Unlock()
   ret:=urls[u]
   delete(urls,u)
   close(ret)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This actually looks really promising.  However, it is possible that the same URL will be called several times before the initial return and this looks like the channel would be overwritten by each of the subsequent addURL calls and the waiting processes can't all read from the same channel at once.  This did give me some inspiration though to make a map of channels within the map and each thread could add to that map.  e.g. urls["www.urlA.com"]["threadname"] = channel  Do you think that would work?  The remove URL call would then range through urls["www.urlA.com"] to close each chan.

Comment: Channel would not be overwritten because of the implementation of `addURL`, and the code calling that. However, this is probably not the best implementation. Seeing that it is already being worked on, instead of waiting, the new goroutine can be assigned another URL.

Comment: Ohhh I see, I totally missed each subsequent call will receive the same channel and then they'll all unblock when the channel is closed.  If there were a couple threads piled up they would all run and then be blocked again except for 1 which would then work its way through.  I get it now.  As for best implementation, I do plan to integrate this into a worker pool and the workers won't be assigned until workOnUrl == true.  Thank you so much for the help!